# Proof of $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n+1-k} = \binom{2n}{n+1}$ via induction

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm having trouble to prove the following formula using Induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{n+1-k} = \binom{2n}{n+1}.$$
I've tried all the usual identities, but they seem to lead nowhere. Is there any trick to this, or is it just not possible to prove this using induction?

I'm thankful for any tip or advice on how to approach this :)

Comment: Vandermonde convolution.

Comment: If you search a bit [in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bn%2B1-k%7D%24&amp;p=1) you can find two problems which are basically modifications of this: [Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{n \choose k}{n \choose k-1} = {2n+2 \choose n+1}/2-{2n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2032707)
and [Evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k-1} {n \choose k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2208043). As mentioned in the previous comment, look at [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: However, neither of those two posts asks specifically for a proof by induction.

Comment: Then we could do induction on $i$, so the full thesis is just the base $P_0$ of the induction, and $P_i\implies P_{i+1}$ is easy because  in fact $P_i= P_{i+1}$ for all $i$

Comment: Thanks for answering everyone. I know the formula is easily proven in various ways, but I was looking specifically for an Induction.

I had to settle with the an inductive proof of Vandermonde's identity though, obtaining this formula as a special case.

Comment: Maybe checking these related posts might help: [Inductive proof for $\binom{2n}{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945404) and [Inductive Proof for Vandermonde's Identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/219928) Especially the first one, since robjohn's answer also deals with the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k-1}$.

Comment: Neither [Evaluate the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k-1} {n \choose k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208043/evaluate-the-sum-sum-k-1n-n-choose-k-1-n-choose-k) nor any of the answers thereto concern induction. If this is to be closed, it would be nice to cite an inductive proof for those looking for an inductive proof.

Comment: What are you looking for beyond the [Inductive Proof for Vandermonde's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219928/inductive-proof-for-vandermondes-identity)? It seems like that can be easily adapted to prove what you want just by subtitutions of the variables.

Answer (score 3):

Select $n+1$ unit squares from a $2\times n$ rectangle. What do you see?

Comment: Is that a hint to an inductive proof?

Comment: Actually you don't even need induction. The picture say it all. Select any $(n+1)$-subset of $\{0,1\}\times\{1,\dots,n\}$. You see a $k$-subset of the fist column and, independent of it, a $(n+1-k)$-subset of the other column. This exactly represents the LHS.

Comment: Your suggestion leads to what I consider the "right" proof, the "natural" proof. (And it proves a more general result, about $\binom{2n}{m}$ for arbitrary $m$.)  But the question specifically asked for a proof by induction on $n$. That seems to make the problem harder.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted yours is just a Vandermonde convolution, which is normally proved
by taking the product of two binomials.

However, if we limit to consider the general Vandermonde convolution with non-negative integer parameters, 
except at most one of the upper parametr which may also be real, i.e.
$$
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  r + m \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le m,n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;r \in R \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
then the convolution can be obtained as the $m$ times iteration of the basic
recursive identity
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  r + m \cr 
  n \cr}  \right)\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le m,n \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;r \in R \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left( \matrix{
  r + m \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 1 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 1 \cr 
  n - 1 \cr}  \right) = \left( \matrix{
  1 \cr 
  0 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r + m - 1 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  1 \cr 
  1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r + m - 1 \cr 
  n - 1 \cr}  \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 2 \cr 
  n \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 2 \cr 
  n - 1 \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 2 \cr 
  n - 1 \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  r + m - 2 \cr 
  n - 2 \cr}  \right) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,2} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  2 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r + m - 2 \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \quad  \cdots  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  n - k \cr}  \right)}  \cr} 
$$

Now, the basic recursive identity can be taken as just the definition of the binomial ,
or if the binomial is defined in other ways it can be easily demonstrated also by induction.

And once you have demonstrated the basic recursion, its iteration leads you to demonstrate 
the Vandermonde convolution.